# Vertical align in CSS, no heights known

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Here's my markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="image.jpg" />
    <div id="contents">Contents</div>
</div>
```

The height of `#container` equals the height of `#image`. 
All the heights are dynamic (they change on window resize). 
The image can not be set via background property.

How can I have Contents over the image and vertically centered in `#container`?

Comment: Why can't the image be set as background? Did you not get it working or is there a particular reason for this choice?

Comment: I'm sure it's pretty easy to do so by setting a background image. This is however unacceptable - the image is a post thumbnail and is rather important in SEO

Comment: I assume as the heights are not known, the widths are also not known?

Answer (score 1):

​This ought to do what you are looking for. I have just set the height of the container and image in css, but if they are the same set in html or using javascript, the result should be the same. The background colour is just there for clarity.

```
#container {
background-color: #333;
height: 200px;
}
#image{
height: 200px;
float: left;
}
#contents{
line-height: 200px;
float: left;
position: fixed;
}
```

​

EDIT: Here is a fiddle of a solution using the old classic margin auto trick. The only thing that may cause problems here is that the parent needs to be position: fixed; which may cause issues for you elsewhere. The main thing is it works, and no heights are set using pixels.

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/h76sy/3/)

Here is the code from the fiddle for a pure css solution with no fixed heights.

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="https://www.google.co.uk/logos/2012/juan_gris-2012-hp.jpg" />
    <div id="contents">Contents</div>
</div>

#container {
    position: fixed;
}
#contents{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 10%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: From OP "All the heights are dynamic (they change on window resize)."

Comment: @SergeySedykh I have edited this, check out the fiddle for a working implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Is the height of `#contents` known? In that case this should do it ([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ttjAS/)):

```
#container{
    position:relative;

    /* For demo only */
    height:500px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
#image{ 
    position:absolute;

    /* For demo only */ 
    height:500px; 
}

#contents{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;

    height:100px;
    margin-top: -50px; /* Half of #contents height */   

    /* For demo only */ 
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: From OP "All the heights are dynamic (they change on window resize)."

Comment: Ai, misread, though he was just referring to image and container height.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of `#contents` you can set up

```
#container{position:relative;}
#contents{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%; /*50% of parent*/
    margin-top:/*negative one-half of container height i.e. if contaner is 4 em -2em*
}
```

You say you don't know the height of `#contents`, though.

Another option is to set the display: to `table-cell` and use `vertical-align: middle`

```
#container{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But depending on what browsers you are targetting for support, that may cause display issues as well.

The more sure fire way is to combine the first option with some jquery or javascript to find the element's height and set its margin-top:

```
content= document.getElementById('content')
content.style.marginTop = '-' + content.offsetHeight + 'px';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h76sy/

**EDIT:** Sorry, had a bug in my javascript, try it now

Comment: Regarding the JS solution - this is what i'm using now in combination with jQuery resize(); It works well on page load, and resizing by dragging the edge of the window, however it is bugged on window maximize / restore.

Comment: I think I have to dig in deeper into `table-cell` solution.

Comment: `table-cell` won't work either: there are two object in the `table-cell`, both with unknown height: the image and the div.